# converting column values to column names and keeping all values without aggregating, Id has duplicate values

Tags: r

Time          |        StartSTop      |     Id

2020-04-01 03:46:03 |   START         |   LB1

2020-04-01 04:27:30  |  STOP          |   LB1

2020-04-01 10:07:08  |  START         |   LB1

2020-04-01 10:40:10  |  STOP          |   LB1

2020-04-02 17:01:23  |  START         |   LB2

2020-04-02 17:40:50  |  STOP          |   LB2

2020-04-03 17:04:56  |  START         |   LB3

2020-04-03 17:38:47  |  STOP          |   LB3

2020-04-04 18:35:34  |  START        |    LB4

2020-04-04 19:11:05  |  STOP          |   LB4

After Pivot Expected Data frame using StartStop as column names not aggregating batch ids

Expected Data Frame:

Id             | Start                  |  Stop

LB1      |2020-04-01 03:46:03 |         2020-04-01 04:27:30

LB2     |2020-04-01 10:07:08  |  2020-04-01 10:40:10

LB3     |2020-04-02 17:01:23  |   2020-04-02 17:40:50

resultant id should have duplicate values.

Comment: dont close the question i didnt find answers in other section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a sequence column first

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
  mutate(rn = rowid(Id, StartSTop)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = StartSTop, values_from = Time) %>%
  select(-rn)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  Id        START               STOP               
#  <chr>     <chr>               <chr>              
#1 LB053272A 2020-04-01 03:46:03 2020-04-01 04:27:30
#2 LB053272A 2020-04-01 10:07:08 2020-04-01 10:40:10
#3 LB053314A 2020-04-02 17:01:23 2020-04-02 17:40:50
#4 LB053330A 2020-04-03 17:04:56 2020-04-03 17:38:47
#5 LB053355A 2020-04-04 18:35:34 2020-04-04 19:11:05
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Time = c("2020-04-01 03:46:03", "2020-04-01 04:27:30", 
"2020-04-01 10:07:08", "2020-04-01 10:40:10", "2020-04-02 17:01:23", 
"2020-04-02 17:40:50", "2020-04-03 17:04:56", "2020-04-03 17:38:47", 
"2020-04-04 18:35:34", "2020-04-04 19:11:05"), StartSTop = c("START", 
"STOP", "START", "STOP", "START", "STOP", "START", "STOP", "START", 
"STOP"), Id = c("LB053272A", "LB053272A", "LB053272A", "LB053272A", 
"LB053314A", "LB053314A", "LB053330A", "LB053330A", "LB053355A", 
"LB053355A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: using above code, i got reslut like this

LB053272A  2020-04-01 03:46:03      NA

LB053272A      NA                         2020-04-01 04:27:30

LB053272A               2020-04-01 10:07:08      NA

LB053272A                                 NA            2020-04-01 10:40:10

Comment: @nickr you need `StartSTop` also in the `rowid`

Comment: i just added it, thanks